# psql parse string with no delimiter

Tags: regex, psql

I kindly request regexp help parsing the following string:

> 154211202251206660

The out put needs to be formatted like this:

> 1-54211-20225-12066-60

The string length is always the same the the break points (-) are always the same.
Many thanks!

PostgreSQL 9.1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following regex with [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

```
^(\d)(\d{5})(\d{5})(\d{5})(\d{2})$
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/fT3uH9/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

Regex can be use with [`regex_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html)

```
regexp_replace(
    TheColumn, '^(\d)(\d{5})(\d{5})(\d{5})(\d{2})$', '\1-\2-\3-\3-\4'
)
```

Comment: Many thanks Pranav.  It turns out I have a co-worker who is way better than me at regex and he gave me the same answer.  I learned 2 things today!

Comment: @J.Clay :  glad to help :)